# Copy a range of rows depending on criteria in a column and paste into a different sheet named as the criteria

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I need some help with VBA in Excel 2010 to write a macro.

I need to know how to copy a specific range of rows depending on the criteria in one column and paste every row (entire row, all other fields too) containing that specified criteria into its corresponding sheet (explained more below). The hard part is that those "destination" sheets might already have some data that needs to STAY there and NOT be deleted. So, how can I write a macro to do what I just described, but when it goes to paste, it finds the first empty row to begin pasting?

I have one workbook with about 5 sheets. The first sheet is the `ALL` sheet that contains all of the data. The next 4 sheets are named `Tree`, `Graffiti`, `Light` and `Pothole`. All of the fields are the same across all 5 sheets. In every sheet, there is one field called `Type Of Service` which is one of those four services (`tree`, `graffiti`, `light` or `pothole`).

What I need to do is filter the `ALL` sheet for each of those 4 services (one at a time), select all of the fields and all of the rows that contain the specified service, copy it all and then paste it into its individual sheet. Those individual sheets may contain some data, so the paste needs to find the first empty row, and paste it there. Concatenate the sheet as it is with the copied rows from the ALL sheet. I need the macro to do all 4 service filters/pastes together.

Answer (score 1):

you get to understand everything by recording a macro and looking at it. 
There's one extra peace of knowledge and that is instead of saying "A1:G3"
you can use Range( Cells(x,y), Cells(x,y) )
and do for example

```
Range( Cells(1,1), Cells(1,3).Select
ActiveSelection.Copy ' or .Cut
```

Go to Excel Options and on the GENERAL tab select USE R1C1 Style. 
The excel shows numbers on the columns too.

Empty cells are found by

```
 IsEmpty( Cells(3,9) )
```

For opening an existing sheet use

```
Sheets("All").Select
```

So

```
dim currentService
currentService = Cells(i, 3) ' current row, 13'th column
Sheets(currentService).Select
```

So it goes like this: 
Either find the filter function and then iterate through the cells by moveDown.

probably the easiest would be 
to sort by service 
find start and end row of each service by iterating on line till reach something else
(that's not empty)
copy the whole range for each service
select the correct book for that service, 
find the empty line on that service sheet (by reading a cell on each row, or if you want to check a few cells:

```
  Function hasRowContent (rownum as Integer) as Boolean
      Dim rowContentCheck
      rowContentCheck = Cells(rownnum, 1) & Cells(rownum, 3) & Cells(rownnum, 7)
      hasRowContent = rowContentCheck <> "" 
      Return
  End Function
```

Count the number of empty rows.
Each row you encounter without content increase the emptyRows counter

```
emptyRows = emptyRows + 1
```

Each row you encounter with content, set the emptyRows back to zero and start counting from here.

```
If emptyRows > emptyRowsToStopAt
    rowInServiceSheet = currentRow
```

Beginning of code...

```
dim emptyRowsToStop
dim emptyRows
For currentRow = 1 To 1000
```

EDIT:

All code explained in my first answer

Here goes:

```
Public Function SheetExists(sheetName As String) As Boolean
' Sheet! It Exists

Dim wrkSheet As Worksheet

SheetExists = False
For Each wrkSheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If wrkSheet.Name = sheetName Then
        SheetExists = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next

End Function

Sub createMissingServicePages()
' start on first cell in ALL
Sheets("all").Select
Row1.Select
Row1.Copy

Dim serviceTypes
serviceTypes = Array("Tree", "Graffiti", "Light", "Pothole")
Dim serviceTypeName As String

For Each serviceType In serviceTypes
    serviceTypeName = serviceType

    If Not SheetExists(serviceTypeName) Then
        ' create a new sheet - at the end of the Sheets list
        Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) ' after 8
        ' and name it
        Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = serviceTypeName ' by now its 9

        ' select it and copy first row to it
        '.. copy header row
        Sheets("All").Select
        Rows(1).Select
        Rows(1).Copy

        ' .. paste in target sheet
        Sheets(Sheets.Count).Select
        Cells(1, 1).Select
        ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    End If
Next

End Sub

Sub updateServicePages()
' if you wish to see the column numbers rather than letters
' change settings in Options / GENERAL tab to View R1C1 style

Call createMissingServicePages

' start on first cell in ALL
Sheets("all").Select
Cells(1, 1).Select

' We'll need this later:
' count the columns
Dim columnsCount As Integer
For Each aCell In Rows(1).Cells
    If IsEmpty(aCell) Then
        columnsCount = aCell.Cells.Column
        Exit For
    End If
Next


' get TypeOfService column number
Dim serviceTypeHeaderText As String
Dim serviceTypeColumnnum As Integer

serviceTypeHeaderText = "type of service" ' ignoring case...

Cells.Find(What:=serviceTypeHeaderText, _
           After:=ActiveCell, _
           LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, _
           SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
           MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
serviceTypeColumnnum = ActiveCell.Column

' sort the whole range
Cells.Select ' first select the whole range
' unremark next line of code if you want to format the data nicely...
'Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit ' if we are already at it
Selection.Sort Key1:=Cells(1, serviceTypeColumnnum), _
               Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, _
               OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
               Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
               DataOption1:=xlSortNormal


' now move the data for each typeofService
Dim serviceTypes
Dim serviceTypeName As String
serviceTypes = Array("Tree", "Graffiti", "Light", "Pothole")
Dim rangeStart As Integer
Dim rangeEnd As Integer
For Each serviceType In serviceTypes
'   we reset for each serviceType
    Sheets("all").Select
    Cells(1, 1).Select

    rangeStart = 0
    rangeEnd = 0
    serviceTypeName = serviceType

    ' .. find range start and end
    For Each aRow In Rows
        If aRow.Cells(serviceTypeColumnnum) = serviceTypeName Then
            If rangeStart = 0 Then rangeStart = aRow.Cells.Row
        Else
            If rangeStart <> 0 Then ' we just exited the range
                rangeEnd = aRow.Cells.Row - 1
                Exit For ' done with this serviceType range
            Else ' didn't reach our range yet

            End If
        End If
    Next ' row

    ' No 'continue' in VBA... and don't want to use a GOTO
    ' If rangeStart = 0 Or rangeEnd = 0 Then 'continue for

    If rangeStart <> 0 And rangeEnd <> 0 Then

        ' .. now copy serviceType to correct sheet
        Dim servicetypeRange As Range
        Set servicetypeRange = Range(Cells(rangeStart, 1), Cells(rangeEnd, columnsCount))
        servicetypeRange.Select
        servicetypeRange.Copy
        ' find empty row in target sheet
        Sheets(serviceTypeName).Select
        Dim emptyrowNum As Integer
        Dim emptyrowCount As Integer
        Dim emptyrowMax As Integer
        Dim emptyrowMargin
        emptyrowMax = 5 ' set this to 1 if there are no spaces in the data
        emptyrowMargin = 0 ' change this if you want an empty row between last data and new data
        For Each aRow In Rows
           If IsEmpty(aRow.Cells(1)) Then ' you could check over a few cells by: & isEmpty(aRow.Cells(2)) etc.
                emptyrowCount = emptyrowCount + 1
                If emptyrowCount > emptyrowMax Then
                    emptyrowNum = aRow.Row - emptyrowCount ' last empty row
                    If emptyrowNum < 1 Then emptyrowNum = 1
                    emptyrowNum = emptyrowNum + emptyrowMargin
                    Exit For ' we found empty row
                End If
            End If
        Next
        Cells(emptyrowNum, 1).Select
        ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll ' ,skipBlanks if needed
    End If
Next ' serviceType

Sheets("All").Select
Cells(1, 1).Select
MsgBox "Done!"
End Sub
```